# How to detect if the ajax request is getting the data from cache or server

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, caching

When an ajax request is made either it takes from the browser cache or from server based on the headers set.

But i want to detect if the response data is taken from browser cache or from the server.

I am using jquery ajax function.

What i have done is i am getting the response headers from server

```
Date: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 10:35:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 10:36:32 GMT
```

and from the browser cache before expiry i get this

```
Date: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 10:35:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.8
Expires: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 10:36:32 GMT
```

Basically i look for Transfer-Encoding and decide whether its from cache or server. But i doubt whether it is compatible across browsers.

is their any other method that i identify the response data is from cache or server?

Comment: Connection might be a better field to parse. Also you might get something out of date too